# Creating list<int> using STIL

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    list<int> list;
    list<int>::iterator a;
    int b;

    a = list.begin();
    cout << "Enter values, 's' to stop: ";

    while(cin >> b){

        list.insert(a, b);
        a++;

    }

    list.sort();

    for(a = list.begin(); a!=list.end(); a++){

        cout << endl << *a << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have to write a program that create a list using STL, add 5 numbers, 
then print them one by one; but I keep getting an error saying: "expected primary-expression before 'int'" and "'a' was not declared in this scope".
Why?
I've written a similar program before and I didn't get this error.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list<int> list;
```

`list` is variable. It hides the class template after this line. Hence,

```
list<int>::iterator a;
```

is a problem.

Change the variable to something different.

```
list<int> my_list;
```

Comment: @oOpSgEo, I didn't understand that comment.

Comment: @oOpSgEo, `std::list` has several overloaded `insert` member functions. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert.

Answer (score 1):

As R Sahu mentioned, you've hidden the template definition of `list` with your local variable of the same name.  You can also use the scope operator to clarify your code for the compiler.   I've shown how below.

I'd also point out that this is an excelent example of why it's good coding practice not to use the `using namespace std` directive.  You wouldn't have had this hard-to-find issue if you didn't use that shortcut.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    std::list<int> list; //optional
    std::list<int>::iterator a; //This is the only one actually required
    int b;

    a = ::list.begin(); //optional
    cout << "Enter values, 's' to stop: ";

    while(cin >> b){

        ::list.insert(a, b); //optional
        a++;

    }

    ::list.sort(); //optional

    for(a = ::list.begin(); a!= ::list.end(); a++){ //optional
        cout << endl << *a << endl;
    }

    return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This works, or at least its suppose to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    list<int> numLst;

    int b;
    int a = 0;

    cout << "Enter values, 's' to stop: ";

    while(cin >> b){

        numLst.push_back(b);
        a++;

    }

    numLst.sort();


    int z = 0;
    for (; z < a;) {
        int outNum = numLst.front();
        numLst.pop_front();
        cout << outNum << endl;
        z++;
    }

    numLst.clear();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    list< int > myList;

    cout << "Enter values, 's' to stop: " << endl;

    int b{ 0 };

    while( cin >> b )
    {
        if( b == 's' ) break;

        myList.emplace_back( b );
    }

    myList.sort();

    cout << endl << "Results: " << endl;

    for( auto value : myList )
    {
        cout << value << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It certainly can be named list, list is not a reserved word.

Comment: Yes, I removed that comment. Thanks.